# Integrating YAGO classes to DBPedia2014

Tags: dbpedia

I am not too new to semantic web and have a complete set of DBPedia2014 English loaded into my RDF store running. Now I would like to add the YAGO class datasets (links, types) into the DBPedia2014 RDF space and could not find a single TTL download (just TSV). The only somehow updated and running YAGO downloads are on http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/downloads/ only tsv files.

One line of such a file is for instance:

```
<id_svyx35_88c_avbfa5>  <Kuldeep_Raval> rdf:type    <wikicat_Delhi_Daredevils_cricketers>
```

Note that `<id_svyx35_88c_avbfa5>`
is not a (resource) url, reading in this line causes errors. Furthermore how can the RDF space figure out to what entity this is referring to in DBPedia (I do have an idea, but this seems to me not really compliant to an RDF Space).

**How can these YAGO files be integrated into DBPedia in an RDF store accepting formats like xmlrdf,ttl,n3,nt,nq ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the yago links from dbpedia

http://data.dws.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/dbpedia/2014/links/